# Why rosmake failed only appear on some packages?

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [swri-ros-pkg](http://code.google.com/p/swri-ros-pkg/source/checkout)

I download by

```
  svn checkout http://swri-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ swri-ros-pkg-read-only
```

Why only motoman stack  failed to rosmake, but all others stack and packages are able to rosmake.

```
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_industrial/swri-ros-pkg-read-only/motoman$ pwd
  /home/ira/code/ros/sam_industrial/swri-ros-pkg-read-only/motoman

  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_industrial/swri-ros-pkg-read-only/motoman$       rosmake
  [ rosmake ] No package selected and the current directory is not the correct       path for package 'motoman'.
  [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: []                                          
  [ rosmake ] Logging to       directory/home/ira/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120630-112405
  [ rosmake ] Expanded args [] to:
  []                                             
  [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack       names.
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/sam_industrial/swri-ros-pkg-read-only/motoman$
```

How to solve it?

Thank you~

---

Here is the directory of motoman:

```
  ira@ira-K42JP:~$ rospack find motoman
  /home/ira/code/ros/sam_industrial/swri-ros-pkg-read-only/freetail/industrial/motoman
  ira@ira-K42JP:~$
```

Here is my path:

```
  ira@ira-K42JP:~$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
  /home/ira/code/ros:/opt/ros/electric/stacks
  ira@ira-K42JP:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36998/why-rosmake-failed-only-appear-on-some-packages?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error says that you didn't put your package in the ros package path. Check out [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/36854/how-to-un-break-a-ros-installation-that-doesnt/?answer=36872#post-id-36872) for more information on a clean way to set up source repositories.

**Edit**: You seem to have several versions of motoman. The result of `rospack find motoman` is different from your current path.

```
/home/ira/code/ros/sam_industrial/swri-ros-pkg-read-only/freetail/industrial/motoman
```

from rospack vs.

```
/home/ira/code/ros/sam_industrial/swri-ros-pkg-read-only/motoman
```

as your current directory.

I'm not sure how motoman got into the subdirectory `freetail/industrial` because it is not in the svn repository you checked out. I would get rid of it or delete the complete check-out directory, i.e. `/home/ira/code/ros/sam_industrial/swri-ros-pkg-read-only` and check out a new, clean version.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-06-21**:
I'm sure I have put. Because I can rosmake other packages or stacks on /media/Data/code/ros/sam_industrial/swri-ros-pkg-read-only.  On that directory, only small part of stack and package I can't rosmake. My ros package path had already added to /media/Data/code/ros

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-06-21**:
I still believe that something must be wrong with your ros configuration. Try calling `rosmake SIA20D_Mesh_arm_navigation` in your home directory please. I guess it will say something like it cannot find the package.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-06-26**:
What is the output of 'rospack find SIA20D_Mesh_arm_navigation'? Does it point to the current directory?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-06-29**:
I found that rosmake SIA20D_Mesh_arm_navigation successfully,although I don't understand why. And motoman stack still do not work. I have revised my original post.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-07-01**:
What's the output of `rospack find motoman` and what's the output of `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`?

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-07-03**:
I have edited the original post for these two output.

**Comment by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on 2012-07-07**:
The trunk was recently broken by a bad check in. It looks like that may be your problem. I recommend working on the fuerte or electric branches. They should be stable.  Sorry. The trunk should be fixed soon.